# CiviCRM Event registration form refreshes instead of submitting when logged out of Wordpress

Tags: civievent, wordpress, permissions, admin, user

I can't seem to get event registration to work for users that aren't logged into Wordpress. If I'm logged into Wordpress admin, I can register for the event. If I'm logged out of Wordpress, the page just refreshes after I click the "continue" button (which is supposed to take me to the next step). Interestingly, there's form validation in place, but that also only works if I'm logged in. If I'm logged in and click continue without filling in the fields, I get errors telling me to fill in the fields. But if I'm logged out and I click continue without filling in the fields, it just refreshes the page.

Anonymous users have the following permissions under CiviCRM Wordpress Access Control:

- access uploaded files
- profile create
- profile edit
- profile view
- access all custom data
- register for events
- view event info
- view event participants
- make online contributions
- access CiviMail subscribe/unsubscribe pages
- view public CiviMail content

I also set up an ACL to allow anonymous users to edit events.

[image]

Details:
Running Wordpress 4.4.3, CiviCRM 4.7.8 on WP Engine hosting.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? What was the fix? I'm going thru this exact thing right now.

Comment: Belinda what CMS are you using?  Have you made sure that anonymous users have permission to Register for Events and Access all Custom Data?